# expectSaga() always times out - even with trivial/empty saga

Tags: javascript, jestjs, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I'm sure it is a newbie mistake, but I am surprised that the `expectSaga()` test below times out. -- advice appreciated!

```
import { expectSaga, testSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';

function* saga() {}

// ✅ ...this passes
it('should be testable with testSaga()', () => {
  testSaga(saga).next().isDone();
});

// ❌ ...this times out
it('should be testable with expectSaga()', () => {
  return expectSaga(saga).run();
});
```

- redux-saga-test-plan@4.0.4
- redux-saga@1.1.3
- react 17
- jest@27.5.1
- typescript@4.6.3

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Both test cases pass.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'll try to isolate. One possibility: my sagas are launched by my own custom hook (creates the channel and runs) - not by redux middleware, etc. So I might be somehow creating this problem. But thanks for checking.